# How to use depth buffer to clip table in libgdx's android game

Tags: android, libgdx, clip, depth-buffer

Table' default clip is to use scissorstack,but scissorstack support only rectangle. And I want to clip it with circle ,so I choose to use depth buffer.

Here are my code,but it don't clip table successfully.
the table displayed  as what it used to be.

```
@Override
protected void drawBackground(Batch batch, float parentAlpha, float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 batch.end();
               //       //1. clear screen
                 Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                //2. clear our depth buffer with 1.0
                Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
                Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                //3. set the function to LESS
                Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LESS);

                //4. enable depth writing
                Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

                 //5. Enable depth writing, disable RGBA color writing 
                Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
                Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

                ///////////// Draw mask shape(s)

                //6. render your primitive shapes
                shapes.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

                shapes.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
                shapes.circle( PositionArray.detail_x, PositionArray.detail_y,100);

                shapes.end();
                batch.begin();              

                ///////////// Draw sprite(s) to be masked
                //8. Enable RGBA color writing
                //   (SpriteBatch.begin() will disable depth mask)
                Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);

                 //9. Make sure testing is enabled.
                Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

                //10. Now depth discards pixels outside our masked shapes
                Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_EQUAL);

                //push to the batch
                super.drawBackground(batch, parentAlpha, x, y);
                //  batch.draw(grass, 0, 0);
                //end/flush your batch
                Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Any help will be appreciate!

Improvement:

After adopting Tenfour04' advice,I change my code ,but it still don't solve my problem.

```
public class MyTable extends Table {
ShapeRenderer shapes;
private final Matrix4 tmpM = new Matrix4();
    public MyTable() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        shapes = new ShapeRenderer();
    }
@Override
protected void drawBackground(Batch batch, float parentAlpha, float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 batch.end();
               //       //1. clear screen
//Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//                  
////2. clear our depth buffer with 1.0
//Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
//Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


                //3. set the function to LESS
                Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LESS);

                //4. enable depth writing
                Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

                 //5. Enable depth writing, disable RGBA color writing 
                Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
                Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

                ///////////// Draw mask shape(s)

                //6. render your primitive shapes
                shapes.setProjectionMatrix(getStage().getViewport().getCamera().combined);
                shapes.setTransformMatrix(tmpM.idt().translate(0, 0, -0.5f));
                shapes.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

                shapes.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
                shapes.circle( PositionArray.detail_x, PositionArray.detail_y,100);

                shapes.end();

                batch.begin();              

                ///////////// Draw sprite(s) to be masked
                //8. Enable RGBA color writing
                //   (SpriteBatch.begin() will disable depth mask)
                Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);

                 //9. Make sure testing is enabled.
                Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

                //10. Now depth discards pixels outside our masked shapes
                Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

                //push to the batch
                super.drawBackground(batch, parentAlpha, x, y);
                //  batch.draw(grass, 0, 0);
                //end/flush your batch
                batch.flush();
                Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   }                    
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out `Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);` and see if the circle is drawing to the screen where you want it (might have to change the table's alpha to something small so you can see the circle through it). Also, I just noticed you want the circle to clip away what's outside it. In that case, I think you want `Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(0f);` and to use `GL_GREATER` for the first depthFunc (for the circle). And translate the transform positive 0.5 instead of negative. You might also try setting the camera's far plane to something small, like 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues:

1) You disable depth testing before the batch is flushed. SpriteBatch only sends meshes to the GPU for drawing when it gets flushed or when you call `end` on it. So add the line `batch.flush()` before you disable depth testing.

2) You never cleared the depth buffer bit. Also, you should not be calling `glClear` more than once. Preferably, you would be calling it before `stage.draw()` not in the middle of an actor's draw method! I would put the following before `stage.draw()`:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

and remove the similar lines from your Actor. There's no reason to call `Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);` since the default is 1 anyway.

3) If your mask shape is in the same units as everything else you're drawing, the shape render needs to use the same projection matrix as the stage. Also, by leaving the matrix at the default, I think you are drawing your mask at Z=1 (depth 0), not at Z=0, which is where sprite batch is drawing. Put this before `shapes.begin`:

```
shapes.setProjectionMatrix(getStage().getViewport().getCamera().combined);
```

4) I suppose it's possible that rounding could cause the GL_EQUAL depthFunc to fail. If you do all the above and it still doesn't work, try drawing the circle farther back.

```
private final Matrix4() tmpM = new Matrix4();

//...

//right before shapes.begin:
shapes.setTransformMatrix(tmpM.idt().translate(0, 0, -0.5f));
```

And then when you set the depthFunc for the masked sprites, use `LEQUAL` instead of `EQUAL`.

Comment: I am sorry ,but it did't take effect after I have do as you said. I will edit my question and add your advice.

Comment: Yes,I find where I made mistakes. I only put Gdx.gl.glclear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) before **stage.draw()**,And now I change it to Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

Comment: I succeed to achieve to clip.But it clear every thing except  what  in the masking area. how can I keep other actors draw as it used to be and change the shape of table to circle?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tenfour04 for help me out this problem.Here is my code after modifing.

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    batch.end();
    // //1. clear screen
    // Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //
    // //2. clear our depth buffer with 1.0
    // Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(0f);
    // Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // 3. set the function to LESS
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LESS);

    // 4. enable depth writing
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // 5. Enable depth writing, disable RGBA color writing
    Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

    ///////////// Draw mask shape(s)

    // 6. render your primitive shapes
    shapes.setProjectionMatrix(getStage().getViewport().getCamera().combined);
    // shapes.setTransformMatrix(tmpM.idt().translate(0, 0, 0.5f));
    shapes.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

    shapes.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);
    shapes.circle(PositionArray.detail_x, PositionArray.detail_y, 100);

    shapes.end();

    batch.begin();

    ///////////// Draw sprite(s) to be masked
    // 8. Enable RGBA color writing
    // (SpriteBatch.begin() will disable depth mask)
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);

    // 9. Make sure testing is enabled.
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // 10. Now depth discards pixels outside our masked shapes
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_EQUAL);

    // push to the batch
    super.draw(batch, arg1);
    // batch.draw(grass, 0, 0);
    // end/flush your batch
    batch.flush();
}
```

Finally,adding ***Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);*** before ***stage.draw()***